# Sending mail by unattended upgrade

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

Some people had met some similar problems but nothing solves my problem; 
my log file

```
# tail -f /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log 
2018-02-18 13:25:37,656 DEBUG No conffiles in deb 
'/var/cache/apt/archives/libgfortran3_4.9.2-10+deb8u1_amd64.deb' (There 
is no member named 'conffiles')
2018-02-18 13:25:37,657 DEBUG blacklist: []
2018-02-18 13:25:37,658 DEBUG whitelist: []
2018-02-18 13:25:37,658 DEBUG InstCount=23 DelCount=0 BrokenCount=0
2018-02-18 13:25:37,660 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: cpp-4.9 
g++-4.9 gcc-4.9 gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 libasan1 libatomic1 
libcilkrts5 libgcc-4.9-dev libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgfortran3 libgomp1 
libitm1 liblsan0 libobjc-4.9-dev libobjc4 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.9-dev 
libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386 libtsan0 libubsan0
2018-02-18 13:25:37,662 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-
upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2018-02-18 13:27:02,483 INFO All upgrades installed
2018-02-18 13:27:02,485 DEBUG Extracting content from 
'/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log' since '2018-
02-18 13:25:37.661632'
2018-02-18 13:27:02,511 DEBUG Sending mail to 'xxxyyyy@gmail.com'
2018-02-18 13:27:02,713 DEBUG mail returned: 0


# cat /etc/apt/listchanges.conf 
[apt]
frontend=pager
email_address=xxxyyyy@gmail.com
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

But the message doesn't go to my email address. 
Of course mailx makes the job:

```
$ echo "Just testing mailx" | mail -s "Yooo woot" xxxyyyy@gmail.com
```

and I receive my message...
I'm using smtp configuration in my .mailrc file

So what can I do?
thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a system-wide MTA configured for off-site mail delivery? Unattended-upgrades does not run in your name, so it won't read your `~/.mailrc`. If you're running with Debian defaults, you probably have Exim installed (check with `apt-cache policy exim4`). Run `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` to configure remote delivery either via smarthost or by direct MX depending on your connection (basically, transfer the settings from your `~/.mailrc`). This will also make your personal SMTP settings unnecessary. Check `/var/log/exim4/mainlog*` for clues if it still does not work.

Comment: At the moment I've finished to set exim4 up to send email correctly by test: `echo "Subject: test" | /usr/sbin/exim4 -v user@my.domain`                    
I'm waiting for UU mail sending to confirm the correct answer. It'll be for an error or a real upgrading...

Comment: It seems not working. Just upgrading libfreexl1. U-U log file doesn't show any message about emailing report....where can I check? p.s. It seems I don't have any mainlog* file....

Comment: Does `systemctl status exim4` report `active (running)`? `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` really should exist unless you manually reconfigured Exim logging. On the other hand if `unattended-upgrades` does not log sending a mail, there's no use looking for one.

Comment: It was an errata configuration about Exim4!. My MTA transferred a root@mydomain insted of myaddressname@domain so the smtp server rejected my mail. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249317/how-to-configure-exim4-to-relay-emails) was crucial for my understanding.